# How to properly check the menu for emptiness in twig?

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

I use Simplify Menu to display the necessary menu markup. How do I make sure that the menu is not empty (there are items there) and if there are menu items, they are enabled?

```
{% set items = simplify_menu('main') %}
  <ul>
    {% for menu_item in items.menu_tree %}
    <li class="{{ item_class }} navigation__item">
      <a href="{{ menu_item.url }}" class="{{ link_class }}">{{ menu_item.text }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

In my work, I use the Twig tweak module, but I can't do a check with it either:

```
{% if drupal_menu('main') is empty %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky as you would expect `{% if drupal_menu('main') is empty %}` to work for checking if the menu exists or not. In reality, you'll want to use the `render` filter for twig. So that would become:

```
{% if drupal_menu('main') | render %}
```

I tested this code in my theme's `page.html.twig` file and it works. e.g.

```
{% if drupal_menu('main') | render %}
  {{ 'Main menu is not empty'|t }}
{% else %}
  {{ 'Main menu is empty'|t }}
{% endif %}
```

There is a very long winded issue here with regard to this:
[[meta] Themes improperly check renderable arrays when determining visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/953034)

There are also some related issues for this.

- [2447049: Add a render filter to twig](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2447049)
- [Checking for empty fields in Twig templates is complicated](https://www.drupal.org/node/2547559)

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_capture is related.